# How to correctly calculate Coss and Cstray capacitance in Full-Bridge LLC?

Tags: mosfet, resonant-converter

To select the correct value of the magnetizing inductance Lm, it is necessary to observe the equation:

[image]

This allows the selected Lm to completely discharge Coss and other parasitic capacitances during the dead time and reach ZVS (zero voltage switch).

Coss - transistor (Mosfet) output capacitance, consists of Cds and Cgs. Specified in the datasheet of the transistor.

[image]

Each transistor has its own Coss capacitance. At the moment of time, only two transistors (Q1, Q4 / Q2, Q3) are operating here.

**Questions:**

1. What is the Coss value used in the formula? The capacity of one transistor or the capacity of two transistors? (there are two transistors in one arm).
2. It is also recommended to take into account the value of the parasitic capacitance of the printed circuit board and the interturn capacitance of the transformer. I don't have a printed circuit board yet.
   Is it possible to guess the value of parasitic capacitance? Or do you need to check on a breadboard?
   Perhaps by choosing a value of Lm slightly below the equation, then we can discharge stray capacitances.

**UPD:** To make a reserve for discharging Cstray, it is worth reducing the Lm value by 0.5–0.8 from Lm_max (in the upper formula).

[image]

Comment: Unless the PCB have large overlapping plane areas for the outputs, then the capacitance is likely to be dominated by Coss. The output capacitance for each half bridge will be the summ of Coss for each transistor in the half bridge. During dead time neither transistor will be turned on.

Comment: Why haven't you shown the full circuit including the inductor and transformer?

Comment: I wanted to highlight the part with the transistors. I updated the picture, now there is a complete diagram. Only on the secondary side are diodes instead of transistors.